# Concat two values into string Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I tried to concat two values of two columns in Pandas like this:

```
new_dfr["MMYY"] = new_dfr["MM"]+new_dfr["YY"]
```

I got warning message:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  new_dfr["MMYY"] = new_dfr["MM"]+new_dfr["YY"]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Do some research on the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dfr["MMYY"] = new_dfr["MM"].astype(str) + new_dfr["YY"].astype(str)
```

Comment: Please add context as to *why* you feel this is a viable solution to solving the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Just posting code is *not* an answer.